# Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules. What rules would be best for a simple app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have received an email from Firebase stating the title of this post with these details:

```
We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
any user can read your entire database
any user can write to your entire database
```

My Firebase database rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what to do. For my app users need to be able to read mostly and write (sometimes to submit stuff). Does anyone have tips to secure this better, or even if I can do anything?

Comment: There are not really any "tips".  You have to write rule that express the security requirements of your app.  Only you know what those are for your app and data.  Start with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  If you're having a specific problem implementing a rule, post the details of what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use Firebase Authentication in your app? If yes, then change the security rules to this :

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

This rule will allow only logged-in user to get and write data to database. This should be a good starting point for a simple app. However, if you are not using Firebase Authentication, then you must implement your own authenticate scheme, but this is just not recommended for security